# add to list with contents from form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that the user can enter in a title and a date.  When the user clicks the 'Add New' button, the contents of the form should be displayed above. That parts works, but whenever they enter in new info, the previous content is just replaced...where it should add to the list.

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Thanks

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beqqC/1/

Here is the code:

```
$("#add").on('click', function () {
    $(".title").html($("[name=title]").val());
    $(".date").html($("[name=date]").val());
    $("#view").show();
});
```

Comment: You are overriding the values with `html(...)`, you should append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of jQuery's append and element creation methods to make things slightly cleaner:

```
$("#add").on('click', function () {
    $(".title").append(
        $('<div>', {
           text: $("[name=title]").val(), 
           className: 'title'
        }));
    $(".date").append($('<div>', {
        text: $("[name=date]").val(), 
        className: "date"
    }));
    $("#view").show();
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ELA4/)**

This will create a div with the specified class within your `.title` and `.date` divs.

Comment: this works, but what if I wanted complicated HTML...then I'd have to put all that HTML into jQuery.  Would there be a way to have a sort of HTML template, and I could just plug the new items in that?  - thanks

Comment: Templating is definitely the way to go if you are going to be creating and manipulating elements. I'd recommend [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) or the [Underscore's templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$(".title").html($("[name=title]").val());
$(".date").html($("[name=date]").val());
```

To

```
$(".title").append($("[name=title]").val());
$(".date").append($("[name=date]").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use append, and perhaps add a `<br />` code to the end:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/beqqC/3/)

```
$("#add").on('click', function () {
    $(".title").append($("[name=title]").val()+'<br />');
    $(".date").append($("[name=date]").val()+'<br />');
    $("#view").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `append()` method. Just put a line break before if you want vertical list

```
 $("#add").on('click', function () {
        $(".title").append("<br />" + $("[name=title]").val());
        $(".date").append("<br />" + $("[name=date]").val());
        $("#view").show();
    });
```